# How to repeat a POST request using Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

Not sure if this is the right stack exchange to ask this, but here goes...

I'm trying to wean myself off of Firebug, which has served me very well for a lot of years. One feature that seems to be missing in Chrome's dev tools is the ability to repeat an AJAX POST. In firebug I can right click on the request in the console and hit "Open in new tab" and the request is repeated exactly as it was originally sent. In Chrome, the same action just does a normal GET on the link, without any of the post data.

Is there any way to repeat an AJAX POST in Chrome's dev tools?

Comment: Probably better on stack

Comment: Did you try Firebug lite for Chrome? Evidently it is still in active dev: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There is an open bug report requesting that feature, though.

[Issue 107006: Feature request: ability to replay a previously made request (esp. XHR)](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107006)

Comment: It looks like as of 3 hours ago it's in!

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107006#c25